# Separately adjusting the height of 2 span elements in div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My Code

```
<div id="open-toolkit">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase" style="margin-right: 4px; font-size: 18px;"></span>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="font-size: 12px">     </span>
</div>
```

Here is my JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/danielyaa5/m2q9aLoa/2/

I want to move the right-chevron icon upward but I cant seem to do so, adding margin top seems to move the whole row down, same with adding padding.

Comment: <div>
                    <span id="open-toolkit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase" style="margin-right: 4px; font-size: 18px;"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="font-size: 12px; top: -10px"></span>
                </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/m2q9aLoa/6/

Method=1

```
<div>
    <span id="open-toolkit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase" 
      style="margin-right: 4px; font-size: 18px;"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" 
      style="font-size: 18px;"></span>
</div>
```

Method=2

```
<div>
    <span id="open-toolkit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase" 
       style="margin-right: 4px; font-size: 18px;"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"         
       style="font-size: 12px;top:-2px;position:relative"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
span{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m2q9aLoa/8/

Answer (score 0):

Just add `position: relative; top: -5px;` or however many pixels you want to move it up.

Answer (score 0):

What if you do the same with `style="overflow: hidden"` on the open-toolkit div?

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS code snippet.

```
#open-toolkit span:last-child {
  margin-top: -18px; /* Change the margin-top: .... as your requirement */
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/m2q9aLoa/7/